# Adding many ramps is slow with AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters setVolumeRamp

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, avfoundation

I'm creating an AVComposition which cuts up a video into many small chunks, to remove the silent parts of the video. To keep the audio pop-free, I'm adding a short fade at the edges of these clips, using the `setVolumeRamp` method on `AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters`.

The problem I'm noticing is that adding audio ramps is slow when there are a lot of them.

Here's the relevant code:

```swift
let mixParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: compositionAudioTrack)
var timeOffset = CMTime(value: 0, timescale: asset.frameDuration.timescale)

for clip in clips {
    // Add a fade-in at the start and a fade-out at the end, if the clip is long enough
    let doubleFadeDuration = CMTimeMultiply(fadeDuration, multiplier: 2)
    if clip.duration > doubleFadeDuration {
        // Figure out the sections to fade
        let fadeInRange = CMTimeRange(start: timeOffset, duration: fadeDuration)
        let fadeOutRange = CMTimeRange(start: timeOffset + clip.duration - fadeDuration, duration: fadeDuration)
        
        // Set the volume ramps
        mixParams.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: 0.0, toEndVolume: 1.0, timeRange: fadeInRange)
        mixParams.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: 1.0, toEndVolume: 0.0, timeRange: fadeOutRange)
    }
    
    timeOffset = timeOffset + clip.duration
}

// Create the mix. This is later set as the `audioMix` property
// on an AVPlayerItem or AVAssetExportSession
let mix = AVMutableAudioMix()
mix.inputParameters = [mixParams]
```

I measured this using Instruments on a 1hr 21min video that has 1421 clips, which would end up being 2842 audio ramps.

[image: Instruments time profiler showing the slow code]

Granted this is an edge case for my app, and I think most videos will be shorter, but I don't love the fact that it just appears to hang for 2 solid seconds as it builds this composition.

From profiling, it looks like all the time is spent in `AVRampsIncludesRampThatOverlapsTimeRange`, which I'm guessing is using a O(n²) way of checking each new ramp against every previous one.

How can I speed this up? Is there any way to set all the ramps in a batch, or skip this check?